# Define and initialize a array to store a certain amount of chars and display them as output

Tags: arrays, char, java.util.scanner

so my main target is this:
Write an line of code that enables me to save certain amount of chars (5 in this example is what I tried) into it and how to display them as output, here is where I am currently:

```
public class TryingCharArrays
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write 5 characters / symbols: ");
        char[] simbolet = new char[5];
        simbolet = sc.nextChar();    // obvsiously this does not work 'sc.nextChar(); ' however I have no idea on how to write it correctly
        simbolet.toString();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(simbolet));
    }
}
```

I know that the first line of defining the char array is correct (at least for my knowledge):

```
char[] simbolet2 = new char[5];
```

However I have no idea how to get the user-input and store inside the array, also I can't do the nextChar(); ti display them as output.

So would love some help / hints.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the whole input as a String and convert it `toCharArray()`

In your case I would read the input as a String and then convert it to an array. In this case you do not need any loops.

And by the way the line `simbolet.toString();` is of no use because the `toString()` method returns a new String and does not convert the original one stored in `simbolet` to a String.

**Update** based on the comments

If you want to achieve to fill in the 5 characters of the array I do not understand why you ask for 3 characters in your output... but never mind.

You can do this in two ways. Once is to read the whole string as once and convert it to a character array:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Shkruani 3 karaktere / simbole: "); 
char[] simbolet = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
```

In this case the length of the `simbolet` array depends on how long the input is. It can be shorter, equal or longer than 5 characters. You could add verification and repeat the request to the user if he/she provides less input.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Shkruani 3 karaktere / simbole: "); 
char[] simbolet = sc.nextLine().substring(0,5).toCharArray();
```

In this case if the input is shorter than 5 you get an exception of course.

If you want to read one line and get only the first five symbols you can have a substring:

If you want to get 5 characters from the user then use the loop. But declare the `simbolet` array outside of the loop or you will lose previously entered input:

```
int end = 5; 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
char[] simbolet = new char[end]; 
for(int i = 0; i < end; i++) { 
    System.out.println("Enter 1 character or symbol: "); 
    simbolet[i] = sc.nextLine().charAt(0); 
    System.out.println(simbolet);
}
sc.close();
```

Or you can combine the two approaches together:

```
    int end = 5;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] simbolet = new char[end];
    System.out.println("Enter the symbols: ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < end && i < input.length(); i++) {
        simbolet[i] = input.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(simbolet);
    sc.close();
```

Comment: I see, however I can't write down:
simbolet = sc.nextLine(); since I declared simbolet as being a char variable, so do I create a String variable? But then how would I fill all the 5 blank spaces in my charArray? I'm confused a little bit..

Comment: How do you want to fill the array? What about when the input contains 6 characters? Or just 3? If you do not have a detailed description on what you want to achieve it is hard to answer the question. And you do not need to create a new variable you can call `sc.nextLine().toCharArray()`

Comment: I want strictly 1 char / letter for each of the 5 empty slots I create in the array, why wont this work? The loop keeps prompting me to make an local variable i, which I obviously already did inside the while loop requirement:

int end = 5;
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Shkruani 3 karaktere / simbole: ");
  whlie(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
  char[] simbolet = new char[5];
  simbolet = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
  
  System.out.println(simbolet);
  }

Comment: Answer updated. This should fix your `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` too I guess.

Comment: UPDATE: Seems I still get an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ' String index out of range: 1...  with this method of yours:


    System.out.println("Enter the symbols: ");
     String input = sc.nextLine();
     for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
         simbolet[i] = input.charAt(i);
     }
     System.out.println(simbolet);
     sc.close();

Comment: Yes, because the input is shorter than 5 characters. I've updated the example to end the loop if the size of the input is shorter than the required amount of characters.

Comment: Then how would I go if I want the user to enter each char seperately?

It makes more sense at least for my current example, and easier to understand this whole thing. I know it must be annoying but you can't imagine how much you are helping me right now, even though this might be nothing for you.

Comment: To enter each character one by one I'd suggest the example almost at the end of the answer: It states to enter only one character. This would be the implementation you need I guess.

Comment: I tried some of them to no success, I mean it just gives me the most confusing errors I've ever encountered which make no sense to me at all;
      char simbolet[i] = (char) sc.findInLine(".").charAt(i);
Did you mean the above answer? It did not work, it gives me 2 errors
1. ' Type mismatch cannot convert from char to char[] '
2. ' Duplicat local variable symbol '

....

Comment: Well, if you use the example I provided right it would work. However from your errors it seems that you mess some things up. Look at the code **above** of this sentence: "Or you can combine the two approaches together:" This shows you how to ask the user for each input character separately.

Comment: I tried the mentioned code again, it just stores the first one and stops, it won't loop :/

Comment: If I count the examples I mention the third one. `int end = 5; 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
char[] simbolet = new char[end]; 
for(int i = 0; i < end; i++) { 
    System.out.println("Enter 1 character or symbol: "); 
    simbolet[i] = sc.nextLine().charAt(0); 
    System.out.println(simbolet);
}
sc.close();`

Comment: Figured it out finally... thank you good sir, once again I apologize for the trouble / annoyance etc... cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could take the first character from Scanner.next:

```
char c = reader.next().charAt(0);
```

To consume exactly one character you could use:

```
char c = reader.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
```

To consume strictly one character you could use:

```
char c = reader.next(".").charAt(0);
```

So You can convert your code like this:-

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write 5 characters / symbols: ");
        char[] simbolet = new char[5];
        simbolet[0] = (char)sc.next().charAt(0);
        simbolet[1] = (char)sc.next().charAt(0);
        simbolet[2] = (char)sc.next().charAt(0);
        simbolet[3] = (char)sc.next().charAt(0);
        simbolet[4] = (char)sc.next().charAt(0);
        simbolet.toString();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(simbolet));
```

Comment: char simbolet = (char) sc.nextByte(); - You mean this? And this does not work I'm afraid, since it wont accept letters (i.e E, e, A etc...). It throws an exception ' InputMisMatchException '

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was asking for, however that code alone gives me an ArrayOutOfBoundsException, should I put an loop for it, so it only goes up to 5?

Comment: As per your choice you can do it...:)